# VBA AZ sort not working correctly

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I hope you can help. 
I have a piece of code that opens up a dialog box then allows a user to select another excel sheet then once that Excel sheet is selected another piece of code is called and it sorts the B Column alphabetically.

The issue I have is that the sort is not happening correctly with the VBA code

If I sort the column manually by clicking on the AZ sort button i get the result in Pic 1

PIC 1

[image]

But when i run the code to sort the B column alphabetically. I get the result in Pic 2

PIC 2
[image]

As you can see the top entry is not correct and Anne Mette Toftager
has not been sorted correctly and the second entry remains further down the sheet at line 83

My Code is below. Can my code be amended to have the sort work correctly and the result be the same outcome as in Pic 1?

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

PS I should point out that the VBA sort must also 'Expand the Selection'

MY CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()

Dim my_FileName As Variant

    MsgBox "Select Denmark File" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    If my_FileName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName


Call SortColumn     '<--|Calls the Filter Code and executes

End If


End Sub

Public Sub SortColumn()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    .Unprotect
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range("A1").Resize(79, lastcol).Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You've mentioned that your data remains 'further down the sheet at line 83'. In your `SortColumn` code you've only resized to row 79 - at what row does your data end?

Comment: Hi Jordan: My data ends at row 151. But it could be different every day I could have more data than that or less data at different times of the week

Comment: Create a `lastrow` variable like you have for your `lastcol` and then use this for your resizing instead of the constant 79. For example just under where you set your `lastcol` variable add: `lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` then change your sort to: `.Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, lastcol).Sort`

Comment: @ Jordan: BOO YAAA!! That got got it working perfectly. Thank you so much for the help. It is greatly appreciated. Much respect from Dublin. How do I get you some points on Stack? do i just select the correct mark at the start of this question? I don't want you to miss out.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm here to help not for points!

Comment: Your a beautiful beautiful man Jordan. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Sub SortColumn()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim LastCol As Long
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2)), _
                            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jean: Yes this works very well the only change I had to make was to change Dim LastRow As Long to Dim LastRow2 As Long because I already had Dim LastRow as Long working further up in the code. also had to change the line LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row to LastRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row but I got there. :-) Jordan got me there previously but he does not want the points so I am happy to accept your answer. Thank you so much for taking the time. Have a great day

Comment: @PhilipConnell good stuff. Helping each other is what its about